# Why not show the help center immediately after a user registers?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, help-center

I see more and more new comers with 1rep posting questions with bad quality or formatting. And every time there is someone (or me) telling them to read the help center.

I don't know whether this is already implemented or not. But I think new users should be taken directly to the help center after they register. And maybe there can be a pop up saying that this is ***SUPER IMPORTANT***. And then maybe new users get to read the thing.

I hope this suggestion will cause less bad quality questions answers.

Comment: Showing help center immediately after a user registers can end up like checking  "I accept  the Terms and Conditions"

Comment: It won't help. These kind of users tend to not read anything anyway. The usual lack of research is a strong indicator for that.

Comment: Given quality of these questions/answers, I don't think one redirect to the help center would remedy this.

Answer (score 4):

Most users will not be interested in such displayment. They want a solution to their questions *now* and are not willing to read through a help center, as much as they might need it. They could be displayed the tour page, which appears much shorter to really *read through*. But in both cases, it will probably be clicked away immediately just like the *terms and conditions* you find in other apps and services.

Comment: But there is a chance that users don't know help center *exists*. Maybe some people are still willing to read it if they know that there *is* one. Like me

Comment: there is the help button right next to the search bar, where you will be lead to the tour and the help center. For this reason, a user who is willing to put at least *some* research into his problem before posting a question is very likely to see it. On the other hand, a user who does not care to search, will most likely never read the help center as well.