# How to handle questions by askers who seem to lack basic understanding of how to ask a well-formed question

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, moderation

I need to understand some basic protocol myself, regarding how to deal with others who lack similar knowledge.

I have noticed (have a feeling?) that more questions recently posted have one or more of these features:

The asker...

- provided insufficient detail to be able to answer the question.
- provided too much detail to encourage someone to read the question and understand which small piece of the asker's solution isn't working. (Yeah, I may be guilty of this one.)
- included images in place of text.
- made no apparent attempt to solve the problem themselves.
- did not include relevant tags (like omitting `sql-server` when it is needed).
- spammed tags or used wrong tags (like including `sql`, `mysql`, `postgresql` when the question is about [Amazon Redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Redshift)).

For example:  In *[How can I calculate the average value from the value that is grouped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74932411)* (now deleted), the asker posts a picture of some data, when they should be posting [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) to help a potential answerer. There also isn't any explanation of what the picture represents (input or output).  The reader must infer this.

This appears to an example of a question that would be easy enough to answer. I just don't know if I should continue to encourage that behavior. I've been answering many similarly-structured questions lately.

I suspect some of this is driven by the local help desk asking, "Can you send me a screen capture depicting the problem?"  That habit doesn't work well for most of the questions I see in my areas of interest on Stack Overflow.

I have posted comments directing askers to relevant documentation about how to ask a question, but it seems like the volume of bad questions is getting to the point where that's all I do on this site—when I'm not trying to work around and excuse vagueness to provide an answer.

Can Stack Overflow encourage reading basic help documentation by mandating that a new account creation requires at least navigation to instructions, like one of the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) documentation?  Or maybe requiring navigation to the About page for a tag (for example, [About `sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)) before being able to apply that tag to a question?  Or perhaps lock some features behind achievements?  (The "I read the About sql page" achievement would allow tagging questions with `sql`.)

Is there already an accepted protocol to handle these types of questions?  Perhaps just ignore them, thereby refusing to help?  Vote to close the question?  (I see that while I was composing this, my example of a problematic post was deleted.)

Comment: If any of the close reasons apply, vote to close. Is there any reason why you explicitly ask whether you should, i.e. why do you question whether you should?

Comment: I agree that questions should be well written and I have failed myself to forfill that in the past. However, it is also important that (1) the user learns and become part of the community (2) get correct feedback. Every downvote, every close vote should include the reason (selectable or free text). Just pointing the the guidelines or rules will not solve the issue for the same reason as point number two above - too much information and not highlighting the important part. (provided too much detail to encourage someone to read the question and understand which, small piece...)

Comment: Please use your close votes and down votes! I'd suggest going incognito and trying to ask a question... then you'll realize just how much the user has already clicked through (and not read) before posting... Sometime close votes and downvotes are the only signal that some folks receive.

Comment: 'Every downvote, every close vote should include the reason (selectable or free text)' if user identified, would be abused for..abuse.

Comment: That linked question as created via wizard. It tells users how to ask proper question. So when a question still ends up being in bad shape, then you can infer that the asker didn't really care. Providing more and more information won't change that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think askers should be encouraged to ask better questions and become part of the community.  But I'm getting tired of the nonsense I have been sifting through lately.  There are many questions being asked by someone new to a programming language.  I have directed people with apparently 0 knowledge to other sources like W3Schools or product docs (RTFM).  For those who are new but trying, I don't want to discourage people from using SO as a learning resource, but at the same time, they shouldn't make it hard on those of us who are here to help.  Just trying to find that balance.

Comment: @Edward Ah, the video game approach.  Often the immediate feedback, even if it's negative, is most helpful.

Comment: Not w3schools please. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478 Consider MDN instead. Yes, a surprising amount of askers appear to have difficulties looking up the documentation for the objects/methods they're attempting to use and prefer to ask a question here instead.

Comment: @user3505708 - “Every downvote, every close vote should include the reason (selectable or free text).” - If those required comments are connected to a user that will open those downvoters to retaliatory activity. I used to provide helpful detailed feedback when I issued downvots to vague unanswerable questions and the only thing that happened was downvotes to my own contributions in other communities resulting in a need to hide them. Why do you believe feedback is required for a downvote but not an upvote? No; required feedback is unhelpful and unnecessary and will hopefully never be required

Comment: @Tom: *...then you can infer that the asker didn't really care...* Is it that, or is it the language barrier? I try to imagine myself trying to ask a question on, say, a Chinese version of Stack overflow. Every single item on the page would be meaningless to me. I would need to spend an hour copy&pasting everything into google translate. Even stuff we take for granted like the question mark button "?" for help would then pop up 6 items with gibberish in each button. It would be exhausting and the temptation to ignore a lot of it would be overwhelming.

Comment: Security Hound - no need to provide the username of the one downvoting. I am against the downvote as a feature, but since it is implemented and most seem to like it... maybe even too much... at least they should be required to give a valid reason for their downvote which can be presented to the questioneer. When the questioneer has corrected the question, the downvoted should also get a notification to review the new version of the question. That should not be too much to ask since the one writing the question presumably have worked a lot to find a solution before asking.

Comment: @user3505708 You probably should read [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr).

Comment: @user3505708 *since the one writing the question presumably have worked a lot to find a solution before asking* Are you sure you're looking at the same site we are? Every day, there are hundreds of questions that are posted for which the asker has made no attempt whatsoever at solving their problem and want answerers on Stack Overflow to do it for them. Also, as for comments on downvotes, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436

Comment: A bunch of related posts: [Why not show the help center immediately after a user registers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307809/11107541), [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266361/11107541), [Why new users don't read the Help Center and what we can do about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373023/11107541), [Introducing new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/997587). See also [meta-tag:ask-question-wizard] and [meta-tag:staging-ground].

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I would not ask a question on a Chinese version of Stack Overflow for precisely those reasons. Why would I? I would find a different site in my native language (or one I was suitably fluent in) and use that site. The idea that there are people being forced to use Stack Overflow despite their language fluency is facile. There are millions of websites on the world wide web; certainly one can find a more suitable site amongst all of them?

Comment: "Can Stack Overflow encourage reading basic help documentation". I think this is irony because I don't think you did much reading yourself before you created this meta post. Because boy oh boy has this been discussed over the ages. No it is pretty much impossible to encourage people to read. They have to feel pain first.

Comment: @Gimby some day I hope I can reject that reality and substitute it with my own. To an extent, I think it can be possible with Staging Grounds, and the [new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364585/997587) is also a good place to brainstorm solutions to the problem. I don't think it's an unsolvable problem, and I don't think people _need_ to "feel pain first". I think they just need to be convinced that climbing the learning curve is good for them. Convincing people of things is an art and a science.

Comment: @Gimby I actually did.  But the words I searched for were not the words used in those posts.  That's the problem with using a computer to perform a search.  It's literal.  It can't infer your meaning.  I always search the site before asking.  When I ask a technical question, I actually appreciate when someone points out it's a duplicate and the link to the similar question.  Plus the different vocabulary provides new insights.

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Offer a bit of help, be it a link, a small edit, or a helpful comment; but don't answer poor questions, just go to the next question and that poorly composed one will roll off the front page (on SO) in a minute. --- Along with links to how to ask, there are links such as:["Add 'I have read the FAQ' check box to the Ask Question page"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147201/282094), more often than not these are click-thrus and do little to improve quality; compared to good advice, and closing OT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there already an accepted protocol to handle these types of questions? Perhaps just ignore them, thereby refusing to help? Vote to close the question?

When encountering in the wild, where appropriate, consider writing a comment to solicit specific  clarifications, corrections, additional details, more focus, etc. I link to relevant Help Center pages wherever possible. There are [some magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/997587) you can use to help write those comments such as `[ask]` and `[mre]` (for other pages like help/on-topic and help/dont-ask, I use Markdown links because the text for their magic links is just "Help Center"). And where appropriate, vote to close the question.

For guidelines for close-voting, see [the MSE FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032/997587), which covers close-reasons that are shared by all Stack Exchange network sites, and [this MSO FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/11107541), which covers those general close reasons, and also covers Stack Overflow's community-specific close reasons. If you don't have enough rep to close-vote yet, you can signal to people who do that a question should be closed by flagging. The close reasons are available as flag reasons under the "needs improvement" option of the root page of the flag-post dialog.

When encountering question in queues like the First Questions queue and the Triage queue, yes, we have protocols / general guidance. See [the FAQ guidance for how to review in those queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/997587).

As for the rest of your commentary in your post, there are prior posts on this subject that- if you haven't already- I recommend to read through. See:

- [Why not show the help center immediately after a user registers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307809/11107541)
- [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266361/11107541)
- [Why new users don't read the Help Center and what we can do about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373023/11107541)
- [Introducing new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/997587)
- See also [ask-question-wizard](/questions/tagged/ask-question-wizard) and [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground)

Answer (score 12):

Stack Overflow has a core operating model that has not changed since it was launched back in 2009. There have been several attempts to help new users to understand the pretty basics, but at the end of 2022 there are still questions like this one.

The model is designed

1. to handle a lot of questions
2. to separate good questions from bad questions
3. to help people to improve posts

The model is not designed to warrant that

1. all questions will be answered
2. all questions will be good
3. all users will be happy

All users can flag questions.

Users with enough reputation might comment anywhere, vote, and review posts.

Don't feel obliged to do any off these tasks on all the posts that you read. If you find a post not worthy to spend your time on it, there is no shame in just ignoring it.

Related tags:

- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
- [ask-question-wizard](/questions/tagged/ask-question-wizard)
- [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground)
- [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation)
- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing)

Comment: The model is also designed to [provide answers very, very quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533). On the order minutes, in contrast to the typical forum's hours or days. Or it could have been accidental.